# Pywinauto run a script on the background

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto, keystroke

I have a certain script that i want to run on the background. I know that similar questions have been asked but i am still having a hard time achieving this.
Here is my code

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Application
import time

app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
#app = Application().connect(title="test.txt-Σημειωματάριο")
app.window().set_focus()
app.window().minimize()
time.sleep(2)
app.window().send_keystrokes("{ENTER}")
```

The above code is minmizing the notepad window but i cant see that enter was indeed pressed. Same goes for other keystrokes that i tried. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `.set_edit_text("\n")` would work better. Not all special characters are guaranteed to work through `send_keystrokes`. It depends on the app usually.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thank you for your answer. Where should i put the `.set_edit_text("\n")` argument?

Comment: `app.window().set_edit_text("\n")` though it may bring the window to focus so you will have to minimize it again. I don't remember the exact behavior.